MD Raid / LVM / BTRFS advice for homemade NAS
Context:
I'm looking to build a homemade NAS to get more flexibility (especially on the capability to add more drive) than commercial solution.
My system will start with 3 SATA SSD drive or NVME (sda, sdb, sdc).
I'll partition the drives in 2

One partition for the OS with RAID1/LVM/EXT4 (unless someone give good advice not to do that). So this RAID1 will be md0 built on sda1, sdb1, sdc1
One partition for the DATA  (sda2, sdb2, sdc2)

For the Data:

I want to be able to loose one disk without loosing data.
Raid 1 or equivalent would cost too much for me in term of drive so I'm looking for a Raid 5 (or equivalent) solution.
I'd like to use BTRFS as the filesystem as it provide snapshot and compression capabilities
I need to be able to add new drive larger than existing one and use this extra space (SHR like)

BTRFS Raid5 profile consideration
BTRFS can directly do RAID5 but is considered unstable as per https://archive.kernel.org/oldwiki/btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Status.html
If we look in details https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-man5.html#raid56-status-and-recommended-practices the issue looks only to be related to metadata location, space reporting and write hole.

I can put Metadata on a dedicated LV on the RAID1 I will use for the OS (md0) => No problem here
I'm not sure to understand "When RAID56 is on the same filesystem with different raid profiles". If BTRFS is doing the RAID, how could it mix different level of RAID on the same FS ?!
Write hole seems the major issue but would only be an issue in case of power loss during writing.

My understanding is that the whole stripe would be affected and that a BTRFS stripe is very large. If only the file beeing written would be affected I believe a scrubing + file restoration from a snapshot would save my life.
MD Raid5 alternative, with or without LVM ?
So if BTRFS can't directly do the RAID5 safely, I plan to use MD Raid5 with journaling (to avoid the write hole issue who also exist in a MD RAID5 without journaling). Journal would be on a LV located on the RAID1 (md0)
I see two different possible setup for the DATA:

With LVM : Making MD RAID5 (md1) with the 3 drives (sda2, sdb2, sdc2), then using LVM to create a PV with the md1 device. Then a VG on the PV, then a LV on the VG. I would then format the LV with BTRFS (SINGLE profile).
Without LVM : Making MD RAID5 (md1) with the 3 drives, then format md1 with BTRFS (SINGLE profile)

When I'll need to extend my setup, let's say by adding 2 x 4TB drive, I'll create three partitions on each new drive

sdd1, sde1 to add to the md0 RAID 1
sdd2, sde2 of 2TB to add the md1 RAID 5
sdd3, sde3 of 2TB to create a md2 in RAID 1

At this point I'm moving (for the DATA) from a 4TB Raid5 system to a 8TB Raid5 + 2TB Raid1 system
From a filesystem point of view, I'd like to see a 10TB filesystem (instead of a 8TB fs + 2TB fs)

With LVM : I would create a PV on the new md2 device (2TB in Raid1), add md3 to the existing VG and extend the existing LV from 4TB to 10TB. BRTFS should now see 10TB
Without LVM : I would do btrfs device add /dev/md2 and BRTFS should see 10TB.

Questions :

I'am right to consider that fixing a BTRFS Raid5 profile write hole issue would not be easily doable ?
I'm looking for advice on what would be the pro and cons of using or not using LVM in the MD Raid alternative ?
If I don't use LVM, is running btrfs balance mandadory after adding a disk or only recommended to "distribute the load" across drives ?
Without LVM, what would be the pro and cons between SINGLE and RAID0 profile when BTRFS will use both md1 and md2 ?


You're overcomplicating this. If sda, sdb, sdc are all equal in size, why would you use RAID1? Just mdraid all three as RAID5 and you will have tolerance for one disk failure. It will present itself as one block device to the system, so you can do whatever you want with it, use LVM or don't. Many benefits of LVM are negated if you are running RAID lower in the stack anyway, but if you're comfortable with it go ahead. Also, I would not recommend BTRFS, but it's up to you. Personally I prefer ZFS but that's another discussion.
